# tmux: is it possible to dim the inactive window and on the same time have transparent background?

Tags: tmux

is it possible to dim the inactive tmux panes and also still have  transparent background in the terminal?

the part of the tmux.conf which dims the inactive looks like that

```
## FROM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532773/change-background-color-of-active-or-inactive-pane-in-tmux
#set inactive/active window styles
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'

# set the pane border colors 
set -g pane-border-fg colour235
set -g pane-border-bg colour238
set -g pane-active-border-fg colour236
set -g pane-active-border-bg colour250
```

But with this setting I lost the terminal tranparency.

I am using gnome-terminal

Comment: You can only change the frame.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532773/change-background-color-of-active-or-inactive-pane-in-tmux

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example snippet of making this work.

Also note to get `vim` to dim you can modify the background in hi Normal to be empty or use a theme that it is already empty. [My custom Nord](https://github.com/casonadams/nord.vim)

If using the `Nord` theme linked above make sure to set your terminal background color based on the README.md instructions.

## tmux.conf

```
######### THEME  ##########
set -g status-style fg=white,bg=brightblack
setw -g clock-mode-colour cyan

set -g mode-style bg=brightcyan,fg=black
set -g message-style bg=brightblack,fg=cyan
set -g message-command-style bg=brightblack,fg=cyan

set -g status-left '#{?pane_synchronized, ¤ ,}#{?window_zoomed_flag, ↕ ,}[#S-#{window_active_clients}]'
set -g status-right '#H'

path="#(if [[ $HOME == #{pane_current_path} ]]; then echo \"~\" ; else echo #{b:pane_current_path}; fi)"

set -g pane-border-style fg=brightblack,bg=black
set -g pane-active-border-style fg=blue,bg=black
set-window-option -g window-active-style bg=terminal
set-window-option -g window-style bg=black

set-window-option -g window-status-style bg=default,fg=default
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bg=default,fg=cyan
set-window-option -g window-status-activity-style bg=default,fg=yellow
set-window-option -g window-status-separator ""
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format " $path "
set-window-option -g window-status-format " $path "
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you so much. The 'terminal' color is what I was searching for.

Comment: Have a look at [alacritty-shell](https://github.com/casonadams/alacritty-shell)

Answer (score 2):

## No.

You are lucky to have transparency *at all* in GNOME Terminal.  That functionality was removed half a decade ago.

It only works when an application (such as tmux) sets the *default* colour as the background colour, with SGR 49.  Non default colours set with SGRs 40–47, 100–107, and 48 simply do not have transparency.

With `bg=colour236` and `bg=black` you are not setting the *default* colour as the background colour.  You are setting an explicit non-default colour.  You need `bg=default`.  Of course, this in turn does not cause the dimming effect.

## Further reading

- Christian Persch (2013-04-22). "[No.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698544#c1)". GNOME Bug #698544.

Comment: ok, thx for clarifying. is there maybe another terminal emulator which allows me dimming and transparency at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

## [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty)

```yml
window:
  opacity: 0.85
```

- Setting colors using [alacritty-shell](https://github.com/casonadams/alacritty-shell)
- Screenshot was using a slightly modified [tomorrow-dark](https://github.com/casonadams/alacritty-shell/blob/main/themes/tomorrow-dark.yml)

## [Tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux)

```
set -g pane-active-border-style bg=color0
set -g pane-border-style bg=color0
set-window-option -g window-active-style bg=terminal
set-window-option -g window-style bg=color0
```

## [NeoVim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim)

Using [walh](https://github.com/casonadams/walh)

```lua
vim.cmd("colorscheme walh-gruvbox")
vim.g.walh_dimming = 1
```

[image]